# Ruby on Rails: Form in multiple steps and form fields of mulltiple models in each step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I'm building a small application in Ruby on rails where I want to take details of a user's house who is moving(shifting) from one place to another and generate an order based on the details provided. 
I have a flow situation where i got stuck and have no clue how to make it work. I'm new to rails, so please help me.

Lets say I have the following models

```
**State**   id:integer, name:string
has_many :cities

**City**   id:integer, name:string
belongs_to :state

**User**   user_id:integer, user_name:string, email:string, ph_no:string
has_many :houses

**House**  size:string, floor_no:integer, elevator:boolean, address:text, city_id:city, state_id:state 
belongs_to :user
has_many :items

**Item**  id:integer, name:string
belongs_to : house

**Order**  order_id:integer, user_id:user, house_id:house, Move_date:date
```

Now I want to take details from the user in 3 steps and then place an order according to the given details.

```
**Form, Step 1** I want to take the following details from the following models

**User Model:** email, ph.no

**House Model** : size, floor_no, elevator, city_id

**Order Model**: move_date


 **Form, Step 2**

**Item model** : All items of the house given as check boxes

**Form, Step 3**

**User Model**: name

**House Model:** Address

Oder Model: Include all the remaining fields and create an order.
```

Can someone please guide me on the structure. Like, How should my form be submitted in each step and at which step do I create a user and house model.

Create them in first step and update in last step- If this is so how do I get the id's of the created models at third step.

Creating them at last step, where do I store them through the stages and how to pass them along.

I have done only basic coding like forms of a single model and some nested models. This however is tricky for me.

Comment: Check this gem once https://github.com/schneems/wicked

Comment: Hi Icicle, thanks for the link, I've checked out that gem, I have one doubt though, Can I update multiple models in the given update function?

Answer (score 1):

i once implemented three stage sign up form which i believe is equivalent to what you need.All you need to capture info in stages.
i used a slider inside a single form and i added three slides with the usual previous and next buttons.

**1. add three slides in *ONE* form

 2. enable the next button only when required fields in present form are filled

 3. initialise the slider/carousel and show one at a time by disabling slide and sliding  only when clicked on next/prev buttons**

i used [anything slider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/)

*for example:-*

***first,use a slide and initialize it***

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider();
```

***in your view,add three slider in a form(multistep)***

```
<div id="slider">

<form action="/to_your_action" method="post">
  ##first slide
  <div id="slide_1">
    <%= render(:partial => 'first_partial') %> 
    ###add one button on this page
     <button type="button">next</button>  
  </div>

  ##second slide
  <div id="slide_2">
    <%= render(:partial => 'second_partial') %> 
    ###add two button on this page
    <button type="button">prev</button>  
     <button type="button">next</button>  
  </div>


  ##third slide
  <div id="slide_2">
    <%= render(:partial => 'third_partial') %> 
    ###add two button on this page
    <button type="button">prev</button>  
     <button type="button">next</button>  
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

*here you need to enable next buttons only when all the required fields are filled,which you can easily do using js/jquery.*

***in controller***

```
def create

##do necessary validation and create ELSE redirect to same form

end
```

***To make use of multiple models you can use three different forms in each slider with the models...such as model1 in form_for of slider1,model2 in form_for of slider2,model3 in form_for of slider3...so on.To achieve this,all you need is to pass three instance variables from the controller..such as @user..@address....@occupation_details for a sign_up form***

Comment: Hi Milind, Everythimg looks good, but does this solve updating multiple models in each step. I think you are doing it for just 1 model.

Comment: Yes,you can by using accep_nested_attributes and including them in the parent form or by using three different instance variables of three different models....i have updated my answer...@Kranthi